# Scraping multiple pages with Curl

Tags: linux, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap data from a website with URL's that follow a particular pattern. Concretely, they are something like this:

```
http://msn.com/21-05-2013/data
http://msn.com/22-05-2013/data
```

Now as you can see the only thing that changes in the URL is date. Is there a curl command to whom I can tell the range of my dates, and it will retrieve the data for me?

I have looked at the official documentation and Stackoverflow, but haven't found anything directly related.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash's number expansion to get all relevant urls.

E.g.:

```
 http://msn.com/{01..31}-{01..12}-2013/data
```

will expand to all dates of 2013 (with some invalid dates like 31-02)

And ofc for sharper bounds:

```
http://msn.com/{15..28}-02-2013/data http://msn.com/{1..14}-03-2013/data
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a for loop in bash, rather than something in curl. Something like this would iterate over all days in May of 2013:

```
for day in $(seq 1 1 31); do
    url=$(printf "http://msn.com/%02d-05-2013/data" $day)
    curl $url
done
```